# Como popular jtable com titulos de arquivos xml

Tags: java

Olá, tenho uma duvida cruel de como fazer uma coisa, preciso popular uma JTable com o uma lista de arquivos xml que estão em uma determinada pasta, porém não tenho a minima ideia de como faze-lo e nem como pesquisar determinada coisa. Como popular uma JTable eu já sei porém como buscar o titulo desses arquivos ( que não estão em um BD ) eu não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer, alguma luz?

Comment: O que já tentou fazer?

Comment: Então, na verdade nem sei como o fazer, oque eu sei por exemplo é pegar dados do banco de dados e popular a JTable, mas no caso agora os arquivos XML estão em uma pasta no servidor.

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar uma tentativa, senao a pergunta cai em ampla demais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ler os arquivos retornar uma lista você pode utilizar o seguinte método:

```
private List<String> lerNomesArquivo(String caminho) {
  File pasta = new File(caminho);
  List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<>();

  for (String nome : pasta.list()) {
    if (nome.endsWith(".xml")) {
      nomes.add(nome);
    }
  }

  return nomes;
}
```

Para utilizar os nomes para popular:

```
  private void popularTabela() {
    List<String> arquivos = this.lerNomesArquivo("C:/Users/Meu Usuário/Minha pasta");
    DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

    int rowCount = modelo.getRowCount();

    // Remove linhas atuais
    for (int i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      modelo.removeRow(i);
    }

    for (String arquivo : arquivos) {
      String[] linha = {arquivo};

      modelo.addRow(linha);
    }
  }
```